# Python coverage: running more than 1 test

Tags: python, code-coverage

I'm wondering is there a way to specify more than 1 test file to run when using python coverage config (`.coveragerc`) file.
If not from a config file, maybe it is possible when running from command line?
At the moment, for 3 different unit tests files I'm using:

```
coverage run test1
coverage run -a test2
coverage run -a test3
```

Can it be any shorter?
Thanks

Comment: you could run coverage through pytest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit (2017-09-25):** As @ned-batchelder says in the comments, prefer [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) over [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) if starting a new project, as nose is unmaintained.

By taking a look at [Coverage documentation](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.4.1/index.html), it looks like that the only mode that `coverage` supports is running a specific module with each command.

You could use a testing framework, such as <s>[nose](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)</s> [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/), to run all your tests, and report the success/failure rate and the total coverage.

## Find out total code overage using `pytest`

1) Install pytest, coverage, and pytest-cov

```
pip install pytest
pip install coverage
pip install pytest-cov
```

2) Run the `pytest` commmand, using the `--cov` flag for every module or package whose coverage you need measured. For example:

```
pytest --cov=foo --cov=bar
```

Sample output:

```
Name     Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
--------------------------------------
bar.py       3      1    67%   5
foo.py       6      2    67%   9-11
--------------------------------------
TOTAL        9      3    67%
```

`pytest` will find your tests if they match the pattern `test_*.py` (or others, more info [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#test-discovery)).

## Find out total code coverage using `nose`

1) Install nose and coverage

```
pip install nose
pip install coverage
```

2) Run the `nosetests` command, with the `--with-coverage` flag

```
nosetests --with-coverage
```

Sample output (when having a single module foo.py):

```
Name     Stmts   Miss  Cover
----------------------------
foo.py       6      2    67%
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.008s

OK
```

`nosetests` can automatically find your tests using some heuristics. For example, if you put your tests in filenames that start with `test`, and create your testcases by inheriting from `unittest.TestCase`, `nosetests` will find them. More info [here](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/finding_tests.html).

Comment: Don't use nose. It's unmaintained.  Start with pytest now.