# Run coverage on tests directory via Travis-CI

Tags: python, code-coverage, travis-ci, pytest, coverage.py

I am unable to run coverage.py in the tests directory from a Python project. I have a tests directory containing an `__init__.py` file and some `test_*.py` files where I define the tests I want to run in the `__main__` block of every test file.

The tests directory is located in the same folder as the `.travis.yml` file which looks like:

[image]

The **script** block works when I run a single file as `coverage run tests/test_errors.py`, but whenever I try to run all the files in the directory it does not work.

I have tried the following solutions:

- [How can pytest-cov report coverage of python code that is executed as a result of pexpect.spawn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51662884/how-can-pytest-cov-report-coverage-of-python-code-that-is-executed-as-a-result-o/51663154#51663154) => which did not work for me as Travis-CI debugger said there was no data to combine, and this solution is not excatly what I am looking for, as the most efficient way is not to list all the test files, just the directory I guess.
- [Python coverage: running more than 1 test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388443/python-coverage-running-more-than-1-test/46389204#46389204) => this solution works but the coverage just is made in the tests directory, and I want to test the coverage of the whole project in codecov. To clarify, codecov shows:
  [image]

Whenever I run the coverage for a single file, codecov outputs this:

[image]

Which is what I am looking for, but when it comes to testing multiple Python files contained in the tests directory. Because as you can see, that is the codecov output when `coverage run tests/test_investpy.py` not for the whole `tests/' directory.

Any help or information is welcomed! An thank you in advance!

(NOTE: for further information about the project structure you can check the project in https://github.com/alvarob96/investpy as it is an Open Source Project)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some more research and testing I found out that [pytest-cov](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-cov/) documentation has an appendix on generating multiple coverage reports for a single test run: https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reporting.html

To execute every test contained in `tests/` and get the code coverage results in [codecov](https://codecov.io/), the script line inside `.travis.yml` should be: `pytest --cov-report term --cov=investpy tests/`, via [pytest](https://pypi.org/project/pytest/) you can generate a terminal coverage report for a project specifying the `tests/` directory.

So the `.travis.yml` when running multiple tests on the same project to combine the code coverage results should be:

[image: .travis.yml file fixed]

So the required packages to get to run the coverage tests on Travis-CI are:

- `pip install pytest==4.5.0`
- `pip install codecov==2.0.15`
- `pip install pytest-cov==2.7.1`

As I already solved it feel free to ask me anything related if you have the same problem and I can help you anyway! If you found this answer useful please rate this answer!